# Log4j2 environment variables are not applied

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

My project depends on a jar that (among other things I need) includes common logging configurations for a number of projects. I can update the jar, but I can't break compatibility with existing consumers. The jar contains:

```
src
|-- main/resources
|   |-- log4j2-bad.xml // not actually named `-bad` but a config I want to overwrite for a unique use case without losing the other classes in the jar
|   `-- log4j2.component.properties //contents=`log4j2.configurationFile=log4j2-bad.xml,log4j2.xml`
`-- test/resources
    `-- log4j.xml // normally the consumer provides their own `log4j2.xml` file.
```

I want to provide an opt-in alternative file (e.g. `log4j2-good.xml`) in `src/main/resources`. Since the [documentation says](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties) that environment variables (and specifically `LOG4J_CONFIGURATION_FILE`) should take precedence over `log4j2.component.properties`, it seems like I could just add `log4j2-good.xml` to the jar, and consumers that want to opt-in could arrange for the `LOG4J_CONFIGURATION_FILE` environment variable to be `log4j2-good.xml,log2j2.xml` at runtime.

However, this does not seem to work.

I added a Main class to the jar for testing. It contains some logging statements and this static block:

```java
static {
    System.out.println("LOG4J_CONFIGURATION_FILE: " + System.getenv().get("LOG4J_CONFIGURATION_FILE"));
}
```

When I set `$env:LOG4J_CONFIGURATION_FILE=log4j2-good.xml,log4j2.xml` and run it, I get:

```
2021-11-17 21:39:32,091 main DEBUG Apache Log4j Core 2.14.1 initializing configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.composite.CompositeConfiguration@6ee52dcd [configurations=[XmlConfiguration[location=C:\<snip>\bin\main\log4j2-bad.xml], XmlConfiguration[location=C:\<snip>\bin\test\log4j2.xml]], mergeStrategy=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.composite.DefaultMergeStrategy@4493d195, rootNode=null, listeners=[org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@2781e022], pluginPackages=[], pluginManager=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginManager@57e1b0c, isShutdownHookEnabled=true, shutdownTimeoutMillis=0, scriptManager=null]
<snip>
LOG4J_CONFIGURATION_FILE: log4j2-good.xml,log4j2.xml
```

So log4j2 uses the bad config, but my `Main` says the environment variable specifies the good config.

When I open Windows system properties and set the system environment variable...same thing.
When I run a gradle task:

```
task runGoodConfig(type: JavaExec) {
  classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
  main = 'com.my.sample.Main'
  environment(['LOG4J_CONFIGURATION_FILE':'log4j2-good.xml,log4j2.xml'])
}
```

same result.

What am I missing!?

Comment: Did you try with `classpath:log4j2-good.xml,classpath:log4j2.xml`? Without the `classpath` URI scheme Log4j2 looks for files in the current directory.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get "Apache Log4j Core 2.14.1 initializing" with the bad config, but my System.out now says classpath:log4j2-good.xml,classpath:log4j2.xml

Comment: After debugging the log4j2 code, I think this may be an actual bug so I submitted a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3193

Comment: I believe you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [confirmed bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3193) in version 2.14.1 (at least).